# How to use =ImportXML to pull data from an html tag with a specific class attribute.

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I am attempting to pull data from a website. Here is the html source code

```
<div class="sort-by">
<span class="totalrows js-totalrows">13386</span>
</div>
```

The code =ImportXML I am using is:

```
=ImportXML("websitehere.com", "//span")
```

I get back hundreds of results with this though as there are hundreds  of spans on the page. I need to obtain the number that resides inside the span. So my question is how do i change the request so that it pulls only the info inside the 'span' with a class of 'totalrows js-totalrows' that way it will draw only that one number for me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use more specific XPath to filter out non-relevant spans, for example by querying only span having class "totalrows js-totalrows" under div having class "sort-by" :

```
=ImportXML("websitehere.com", "//div[@class='sort-by']/span[@class='totalrows js-totalrows']")
```

or if you want simpler XPath to query span element with a class of 'totalrows js-totalrows', this will do :

```
=ImportXML("websitehere.com", "//span[@class='totalrows js-totalrows']")
```

Anyway, the point is we use square brackets (`[]`) to declare specification of element to be selected (a.k.a filter) in XPath.